# Contact form 7 hooks, where can we write it to take it's advantage

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

In wordpress I have comeaccross the word hooks, I have implemented few of them in my custom theme's function.php, I am trying to edit someone's code, I see he wrote few hooks inside the plugins settings.php file itself.

ex- We are using the plugin Contact Form 7, and wanted to add some more data to email before sending them, hence he wrote the hooks inside settings.php which I am not sure is correct or wrong.

Can some-one advice me as what is the best place to write our hooks for wordpress plugins so that it will not affect the plugin when there is an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue to use functions.php. If it starts to become a bit cluttered separate into includes. ie...

include_once('inc/cf7_custom.php');